# Kindly help me resolve error in this c++ code

Tags: c++, error-handling, compiler-errors, c++14, out-of-memory

This question is from GFG: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/n-queen-problem0315/1# (N Queen Problem)

This is my code:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int valid;
class Solution{
public:

    bool isSafe(int n, int arr[n][n], int row, int col){
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<col;i++){
            if(arr[row][i]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        for(i=row,j=col;i>=0&&j>=0;i--,j--){
            if(arr[i][j]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        for(i=row,j=col;i<n&&j>=0;i++,j--){
            if(arr[i][j]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    void QueenUtil(int n, int arr[n][n], int col, vector<vector<int>> &ans){
        if(col==n){
            valid=1;
            vector<int> v;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    if(arr[j][i]){
                        v.push_back(j);
                    }
                }
            }
            ans.push_back(v);
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(isSafe(n,arr,i,col)){
                arr[i][col] = 1;
                QueenUtil(n,arr,col+1,ans);
                arr[i][col] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    vector<vector<int>> nQueen(int n) {
        // code here
        valid=0
        vector<vector<int>> ans(n);
        int arr[n][n];
        memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));
        int col = 0;
        QueenUtil(n,arr,col,ans);
        return ans;
    }
};

int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        Solution ob;
        vector<vector<int>> ans = ob.nQueen(n);
        if(ans.size()==1){
            cout<<-1<<endl;
        }else{
            for(int i=0;i<ans.size();i++){
                cout<<"[";
                for(int u:ans[i]){
                    cout<<u<<" ";
                }
                cout<<"] ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the compilation error:

```
prog.cpp:8:33: error: use of parameter outside function body before ‘]’ token
     bool isSafe(int n, int arr[n][n], int row, int col){
                                 ^
prog.cpp:8:36: error: use of parameter outside function body before ‘]’ token
     bool isSafe(int n, int arr[n][n], int row, int col){
                                    ^
prog.cpp:8:37: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token
     bool isSafe(int n, int arr[n][n], int row, int col){
                                     ^
prog.cpp:8:39: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’
     bool isSafe(int n, int arr[n][n], int row, int col){
```

Comment: You cannot declare 2D arrays like that in C++. As `n` is less than 10, the simplest way here is to declare `int arr[10][10]`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Just use `vector<vector<int>> arr(n, vector<int>(n))` instead of `int arr[10][10]` when declaring it in the `nQueen(int n)` function and pass just `vector<vector<int>>` as a parameter for  `void QueenUtil(int n, int arr[n][n], int col, vector<vector<int>> &ans)` and bool `isSafe(int n, int arr[n][n], int row, int col)`.

Why cant I use `int arr[n][n]` instead? 
That's because the compiler needs to know about the size of the array (in your case the value stored in `n`) at compile time. But your variable is not a `const` value. That means that you cant use it to define a multidimensional array. Plus C++ does not allow to use a function parameter to be used in another function parameter. This is *partly* because the spec doesn't state a definite way to resolve the function arguments (left to right or right to left).